# Resizing view down in size by setting height & width in code doesn't update correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

In my application we have a view containing a number of nested views, in order to provide some common functionalities, i.e.:

In this instance:

an ErrorPanelView (UserControl) with a *-sized main content grid cell and a fixed-width cell that holds a panel of validation messages (if any validation failed) - this panel has a fixed width and is visible or collapsed as needed.

The main content holds a ButtonPanelView again with a *-sized content grid cell and a fixed-height cell that holds standard buttons (ok, cancel, etc)

The main content then holds the 'actual' view - this may have a min/maxHeight & min/maxWidth, for this example min/max values are the same, so the size is static.

When the view has a validation error, and the validationPanel becomes visible. The overall view will resize (expand in width) as it is supposed to, so so far all is well. However, when the validation errors are handled by the user, the validation panel should disappear, and the window should resize down to its original size.  What does happen is that the inner views will resize correctly (so it seems, at least), but the outer view (the ErrorPanelView usercontrol) will keep its bigger dimensions, and leave a black field where the validation panel was visible previously.

The moment the user clicks the usercontrol, the userControl will snap to its intended (original) size.

[image]

I can't figure out what I am missing here.

As far as I can tell the dimensions are calculated correctly and the UserControl's height and width are set to the right values, but is there something wrong with the sequence? - or should I explicitly call some systemEvent?

Or something else entirely??

I'm stumped.

```cs
private static void CalculateWindowSize(BaseWindow window, List<View> views, bool adjustCurrentSize)
        {
            // Calculate the extra space the window consumes.
            View topView = views.First();
            double heightDiff = window.ActualHeight - topView.ActualHeight;

            double widthDiff = window.ActualWidth - topView.ActualWidth;
            double ww = window.Width; //
            double tvw = topView.Width;


            const double zeroTolerance = 0.6;
            double maxHeightMax = 0, maxWidthMax = 0;
            double maxHeightSum = 0, maxWidthSum = 0;
            double minHeightMax = 0, minWidthMax = 0;
            double minHeightSum = 0, minWidthSum = 0;
            double heightSum = 0, widthSum = 0;
            double heightMax = 0, widthMax = 0;
            foreach (View view in views)
            {
                ViewSizeBehaviour viewHeightBehaviour = GetHeightSizeBehaviour(view);
                ViewSizeBehaviour viewWidthBehaviour = GetWidthSizeBehaviour(view);

                switch (viewHeightBehaviour)
                {
                    case ViewSizeBehaviour.Sum:
                    {
                        if (!double.IsInfinity(view.MaxHeight)) maxHeightSum += view.MaxHeight;
                        if (Math.Abs(view.MinHeight) > zeroTolerance) minHeightSum += view.MinHeight;

                        // Default to MinHeight if WindowHeight not defined
                        if (!double.IsNaN(view.WindowHeight)) heightSum += view.WindowHeight;
                        else heightSum += view.MinHeight;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ViewSizeBehaviour.Max:
                    {
                        if (!double.IsInfinity(view.MaxHeight)) maxHeightMax = Math.Max(maxHeightMax, view.MaxHeight);
                        if (Math.Abs(view.MinHeight) > zeroTolerance) minHeightMax = Math.Max(minHeightMax, view.MinHeight);

                        // Default to MinHeight if WindowHeight not defined
                        heightMax = Math.Max(heightMax, !double.IsNaN(view.WindowHeight) ? view.WindowHeight : view.MinHeight);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                switch (viewWidthBehaviour)
                {
                    case ViewSizeBehaviour.Sum:
                    {
                        if (!double.IsInfinity(view.MaxWidth)) maxWidthSum += view.MaxWidth;
                        if (Math.Abs(view.MinWidth) > zeroTolerance) minWidthSum += view.MinWidth;

                        // Default to MinWidth if WindowWidth not defined
                        if (!double.IsNaN(view.WindowWidth)) widthSum += view.WindowWidth;
                        else widthSum += view.MinWidth;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ViewSizeBehaviour.Max:
                    {
                        if (!double.IsInfinity(view.MaxWidth)) maxWidthMax = Math.Max(maxWidthMax, view.MaxHeight);
                        if (Math.Abs(view.MinWidth) > zeroTolerance) minWidthMax = Math.Max(minWidthMax, view.MinWidth);

                        // Default to MinWidth if WindowWidth not defined
                        widthMax = Math.Max(widthMax, !double.IsNaN(view.WindowWidth) ? view.WindowWidth : view.MinWidth);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (adjustCurrentSize)
            {
                window.Height = Math.Max(heightSum, heightMax) + heightDiff;
                window.Width = Math.Max(widthSum, widthMax) + widthDiff;
            }

            // Only set maximum height & width if they are greater than zero. Otherwise all views have specified Infinity as max height

            double maxHeight = Math.Max(maxHeightSum, maxHeightMax);
            double maxWidth = Math.Max(maxWidthSum, maxWidthMax);
            if (Math.Abs(maxHeight) > zeroTolerance)
            {
                window.MaxHeight = maxHeight + heightDiff;
                if (window.MaxHeight < window.Height || window.MaxHeight < window.ActualHeight)
                {
                    window.Height = window.MaxHeight;
                }
            }
            if (Math.Abs(maxWidth) > zeroTolerance)
            {
                window.MaxWidth = maxWidth + widthDiff;
                if (window.MaxWidth < window.Width || window.MaxWidth < window.ActualWidth)
                {
                    window.Width = window.MaxWidth;
                }
            }

            // Minimum height & width are the maximum of either the sum or max calculations

            window.MinHeight = Math.Max(minHeightSum, minHeightMax) + heightDiff;
            window.MinWidth = Math.Max(minWidthSum, minWidthMax) + widthDiff;
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags on the question say `WPF` and `XAML`, but the code is written like this is a winforms application, so I'm not 100% sure how to answer this.
I'll proceed under the assumption that the tags are correct and you are new to WPF.

Basically all the code in your question is unneeded in a WPF application.  One of the main advantages of WPF over Winforms is automatic resizing of content; which Winforms did not do for you.

In WPF, you set up the XAML in your UserControl so that when you have an error condition, the Validation Error UserControl becomes Visibile.  You just bind a boolean property to the `Visibility` property of the UserControl (use a ValueConverter also) and then when the error is handled, the boolean is set to false and the validation UserControl disappears and WPF automatically resizes the rest of the content.  You don't write any code for resizing (that's the old Winforms way).

Of course, there's plenty of things to learn in XAML to set up your UserControls so that the automatic resizing happens the way you want it to, but the cumbersome code writing with all the math and calculating and redrawing is just not needed anymore.

Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction.  There's a ton of tutorials and help out there for setting up UserControls in XAML and binding boolean properties to the Visibility property on your Controls and using IValueConverters.